# Create react app + React lazy + Absolute Imports

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, create-react-app, dynamic-import

I have set up jsconfig.json as described in cra documentation. 
[https://create-react-app.dev/docs/importing-a-component#absolute-imports][1]

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "src"
  },
  "include": ["src"]
}
```

It is working fine if write directly to the file.

```
import Test from 'pages/Test'
```

But when I try to load it lazy, it is creating problem.

```
const TestPage= React.lazy(() => import('pages/Test'));
```

Doing this giving error cannot able to find module: pages/Test

But if I write relative path, it is working fine.

```
const TestPage= React.lazy(() => import('../../pages/Test'));
```

So, my question is how to import module on dynamically by using absolute path?

Thanks

Comment: CRA uses webpack, and looking at the [webpack module resolution docs](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/module-resolution/#module-paths) I'm guessing the algorithm doesn't work for dynamic imports?

Answer (score 1):

try to add a `"paths"` property to `"compilerOptions"` for `pages` like this:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "paths": {
       "pages": "src/pages"
    }
  },
  "include": ["src"]
}
```

Answer (score -2):

I think you may **Suspense** missed wrapper component.

```
import React, { lazy, Suspense } from 'react';

const TestPage= React.lazy(() => import('pages/Test'));

const renderLoader = () => <p>Loading</p>;

const DetailsComponent = () => (
   <Suspense fallback={renderLoader()}>
      <TestPage />
   </Suspense>
)
```

https://reactjs.org/docs/code-splitting.html

Comment: What does this have to do with the question?

Comment: @JaredSmith Reference for how to use Suspense Wrapper component

Comment: No, what does the Suspense wrapper component have to do with *module path resolution*?

Comment: Without using Suspense if you try to import lazy load component means react will show error, to avoid that use Suspense, This will wait till the dynamic import component to load.

Comment: I give up on trying to explain it to you. The problem is that module path resolution is failing it has nothing to do with Suspense or lack thereof: *the OPs code works fine with a relative path*. This is an issue with webpack, or CRA's webpack config.